# C#, Visual studio 2012, find default programs to run a specific extension

Tags: c#, file, registry, file-extension

I'm looking for a way for the file information program I'm making to check what installed program uses a specific extension (which the user choses in runtime) since as I found the same extension can be used by multiple programs. I know it has to do with the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT folder in the registry but I can't seem to figure out a simple way to get this information. Is there one?

EDIT:

Sorry, clarification:

My program will check the file extension of a file opened by the user. I'd like the program to be able to check what program installed on the computer handles the extension specified.

Example:

The user opens the file "file.txt" I'd like my program to be able to say that "extension = .txt Default program = notepad.exe"

I know that these values are held in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the registry but every extension has different folders and values. I can't write a line of code telling the program to check the registry at 'n' point because i can'T find any default folder hierarchy to follow.

(Example: .txt has 3 folders and one folder called ShellNew has a value called itemName which specifies notepad.exe, .cpp has two folders but there is not one called ShellNew, but the base folder has a value called default that says "VisualStudio.cpp.11.0" but it does not specify an exe file or anything)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question exactly, if you could, could you add some code or at least expand your question with a possible scenario.  I bet it would help the community respond with a more relevant answer.

If you are trying to pull values out of the Registry, using a `RegistryKey` works.

```
RegistryKey reg1 = new Registry.ClassesRoot;
string[] values1 = reg1.OpenSubKey("txtfile").GetValueNames();
```

Will get you the names of the values held.  I don't exactly understand what you wish to get out though but to better illustrate.

```
object InstallationDirectory = reg.OpenSubKey(RegistryEntryPath).GetValue("Client Installation Directory");
```

would return you the specified installation path of a program.  This may put you on the right track.

EDIT:

After reading your edited post I did a little research and it looks like the FriendlyTypeName is something you might be seeking.

```
object path = reg1.OpenSubKey("txtfile").GetValue("FriendlyTypeName");
```

Which returned this string, "@C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe,-469"

Comment: Thanks! I added some clarification, I hope it's better now

Comment: Is that more the direction you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. I mean it works as long as i want a txt file, but this doesn't seem to work on a cpp file for example, where it just says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." When i opened a png file it set a link to a dll file, so this doesn't seem to be the solution sadly.

Comment: I just checked with an rtf file, and it worked so this method seems to favor Windows native extensions.